# Invalid template error in CloudFormation sdc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

**I'm trying to generate an instance with default settings used throughout EC2 creation, however, when I upload to CloudFormation and launch, the following error appears**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svlvV.png)

**This is the code/file used:**

```html
Parameters:
  SecurityGroupDescription:
    Description: Descrição do Security Group
    Type: String
  CidrIppescription:
    Description: Descrição do IP para acesso SSH
    Type: String


Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: sa-east-1c
      ImageId: ami-0ef5d9d9491fda325
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref ServerSecurityGroup


MeuEIP:
  Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
  Properties:
    InstanceId: !Ref MyInstance


ServerSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: !Ref SecurityGroupDescription
    SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 22
      ToPort: 22
      CidrIp: !Ref CidrIpDescription
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be in English on this Stack.

Comment: @SolarMike isn't it just the description strings that aren't english (or did I miss something)? I don't find that particularly problematic.

Comment: @david-fong check the editing history - it was translated after my comment, so yes you did miss something.

Answer (score 1):

You have **indentation** issues. `MeuEIP` and `ServerSecurityGroup` must be intended to be under `Resources`:

```
Parameters:
  SecurityGroupDescription:
    Description: Descrição do Security Group
    Type: String
  CidrIppescription:
    Description: Descrição do IP para acesso SSH
    Type: String


Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: sa-east-1c
      ImageId: ami-0ef5d9d9491fda325
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref ServerSecurityGroup


  MeuEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref MyInstance


  ServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Ref SecurityGroupDescription
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: !Ref CidrIpDescription
```